# declaration of a Multidimensional array without index numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, c++11, multidimensional-array

I was wondering how it is possible to declare char arrays this way:

```
char szArray[]={"one"};
char szArrayTwo[][6]={{"one"},{"two"},{"three"}};
```

But this way doesn't work

```
char szArrayTwo[][]={{"one"},{"two"},{"three"}};
```

**NOTE:**
I am aware of the c++ tag even though it should be c, but it is being used in the c++ context with a c++ compiler

Comment: The compiler answered your question with the error you received. In both C++ and C, *all* but the most superior dimension of a multi-dim array must be specified when providing an initializer list. Your second snippet doesn't do so. And related, if you want to do what it appears you're trying (an array of constant string literals) you can do so with simple `const char *szArray[] = { "one", "two", "three" };` i.e. a simple array of `const char*`. But note, the strings in such a definition are NOT writable.

Comment: I just had a look at the error messages that are generated, and they don't seem so "obvious" to me: 
-missing subscript
-array bounds overflow .
Of course cannot write on it

Comment: Both of your first arrays *and* their elements are writable. The one I posted, the array is writable (its just an array of pointers) but the strings within are read-only literals. The missing subscript message was the one I referred to. I too would like better verbosity in error messages (who doesn't?), but the subscript being the only difference between your code that works and your code that doesn't is a pretty strong indicator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact it could be done for constant expressions used as initializers. But in this case for example for character arrays the compiler has to calculate the maximum length of string literals. And it is more difficult if an array is multidimensional.
The task will be more complicated if initializers are calculated at run time. In fact it is impossible to generate an appropriate code by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

In c++, an array with 2 dimension or more, the rightmost dimensions must always be defined.

Comment: does this also apply to the c standard?

Comment: all, or all but one must be defined

Comment: Yes, a dimension must be declared

Comment: @Emi987: your statement makes it seem like all but one can be omitted, when in fact at most one can be omitted.

Comment: My bad, I meant that but I did not add an "s" to my dimension. Edited. Thanks!

Comment: @bacon Yes, array syntax is the same in C as C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
string ArrayOne[] { "one","two","three" };
```

will work, and so will

```
char* ArrayTwo[] { "one","two","three" };
```

but a true multidimensional array must have at most one undefined dimension size (the leftmost)